# how to save subset data of one collection in another collection in SpringBoot Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have 1 collection namely **profile** now since it has lots of properties and since in future I will be needing more properties i decided to add new data in new collection namely **profile_details** .I will be keeping 1 field in **profile_details** namely profileId whose value will be same as primary key of collection **profile**.

I will be saving data of profile in profile collection using **profileRepository.save(profile)**

In order to save data in **profile_details** collection I am using aggregation pipeline in order to save data of **profile_details** collection but $out operator replaces documents instead of inserting new documents.Below is my sample code.Any help will be deeply appreciated

**Profile.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.juv.common.bean.model.RecentHealthMetricData;
import com.juv.common.enums.CurrentLanding;
import com.juv.common.enums.MFAPreference;
import com.juv.common.enums.Status;
import com.juv.common.primary.bean.model.Answer;
import com.juv.common.primary.bean.model.DeviceIntegrations;
import com.juv.common.primary.bean.model.DeviceToken;

@Document(collection = "profile")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Component
public class Profile extends ProfileDetails implements Serializable {

    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6608898578832145751L;

    @Id
    private String profileId;

    @Field("kibo_user_id")
    @JsonProperty("kibo_user_id")
    private String kiboUserId;

    @Field("new_recommendations")
    @JsonProperty("new_recommendations")
    private List<String> newRecommendations;

    @Field("kibo_id")
    @JsonProperty("kibo_id")
    private String kiboId;
    
    @Field("original_kibo_id")
    @JsonProperty("original_kibo_id")
    private String originalKiboId;

    @Field("email")
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    @Field("country")
    @JsonProperty("country")
    private String country;

    @Field("first_name")
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Field("last_name")
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @CreatedDate
    @Field("created_date")
    @JsonProperty("created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Field("registration_date")
    @JsonProperty("registration_date")
    private Date registrationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Field("last_modified")
    @JsonProperty("last_modified")
    private Date lastModified;

    @Field("phi_mapping_id")
    @JsonProperty("phi_mapping_id")
    private String phiMappingId;

    @Field("phone_number")
    @JsonProperty("phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Field("origin")
    @JsonProperty("origin")
    private String origin;

    @Field("gender")
    @JsonProperty("gender")
    private String gender;

    @Field("status")
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Status status;
    
    @Field("current_landing")
    @JsonProperty("current_landing")
    private CurrentLanding currentLanding;

    @Field("mfa_preference")
    @JsonProperty("mfa_preference")
    private MFAPreference mfaPreference;

    @Field("profile_recommendation_info_id")
    @JsonProperty("profile_recommendation_info_id")
    private String profileRecommendationInfoId;
    
    @Field("oldest_profile_recommendation_info_id")
    @JsonProperty("oldest_profile_recommendation_info_id")
    private String oldestProfileRecommendationInfoId;

    @Field("last_question")
    @JsonProperty("last_question")
    private String lastQuestion;

    @Field("answers")
    @JsonProperty("answers")
    private Answer[] answers;
    
    @Field("is_account_locked")
    @JsonProperty("is_account_locked")
    private boolean isAccountLocked;
    
    @Field("device_integrations")
    @JsonProperty("device_integrations")
    private DeviceIntegrations deviceIntegrations ;
    
    @Field("profile_photo")
    @JsonProperty("profile_photo")
    private String profilePhoto;

    @Field("device_token_list")
    @JsonProperty("device_token_list")
    private List<DeviceToken> deviceTokenList;
    
    @Field("unit_map")
    @JsonProperty("unit_map")
    private Map<String,String> unitMap;
    
    @Field("recent_health_metric_values")
    @JsonProperty("recent_health_metric_values")
    private Map<String,RecentHealthMetricData> recentHealthMetricValues;
    
    @Field("last_recommendation_info_date")
    @JsonProperty("last_recommendation_info_date")
    private Date lastRecommendationInfoDate;

    @Field("terms_conditions")
    @JsonProperty("terms_conditions")
    private boolean termsConditions;
    
    @Field("health_metric_preferences")
    @JsonProperty("health_metric_preferences")
    private Map<String, String> healthMetricPreferences;

    @Field("device_preferences")
    @JsonProperty("device_preferences")
    private Map<Integer, String> devicePreferences;

    @Field("pinpoint_custom_atributes")
    @JsonProperty("pinpoint_custom_atributes")
    private Map<String,String> pinpointCustomAttributes;
    
    @Field("opt_juvlab_customer")
    @JsonProperty("opt_juvlab_customer")
    private boolean optJuvLabsCustomer;
    
    @Field("deleted")
    @JsonProperty("deleted")
    private boolean deleted;
    
    @Field("deleted_timestamp")
    @JsonProperty("deleted_timestamp")
    private Instant deletedTimestamp;
    
    @Field("daily_action_count_clevertap")
    @JsonProperty("daily_action_count_clevertap")
    private int dailyActionCountClevertap;
    
    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getKiboUserId() {
        return kiboUserId;
    }

    public void setKiboUserId(String kiboUserId) {
        this.kiboUserId = kiboUserId;
    }

    public String getKiboId() {
        return kiboId;
    }

    public void setKiboId(String kiboId) {
        this.kiboId = kiboId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        if (email != null) {
            email = email.toLowerCase();
        }
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public Date getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }

    public String getPhiMappingId() {
        return phiMappingId;
    }

    public void setPhiMappingId(String phiMappingId) {
        this.phiMappingId = phiMappingId;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public CurrentLanding getCurrentLanding() {
        return currentLanding;
    }

    public void setCurrentLanding(CurrentLanding currentLanding) {
        this.currentLanding = currentLanding;
    }

    public MFAPreference getMfaPreference() {
        return mfaPreference;
    }

    public void setMfaPreference(MFAPreference otpPreference) {
        this.mfaPreference = otpPreference;
    }

    public String getProfileRecommendationInfoId() {
        return profileRecommendationInfoId;
    }

    public void setProfileRecommendationInfoId(String profileRecommendationInfoId) {
        this.profileRecommendationInfoId = profileRecommendationInfoId;
    }

    public String getLastQuestion() {
        return lastQuestion;
    }

    public void setLastQuestion(String lastQuestion) {
        this.lastQuestion = lastQuestion;
    }

    public Answer[] getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(Answer[] answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
    
    public boolean isAccountLocked() {
        return isAccountLocked;
    }

    public void setAccountLocked(boolean isAccountLocked) {
        this.isAccountLocked = isAccountLocked;
    }

    public enum ORIGIN {
        APP,
        KIBO,
        SHOPIFY
    }

    public String getProfilePhoto() {
        return profilePhoto;
    }

    public void setProfilePhoto(String profilePhoto) {
        this.profilePhoto = profilePhoto;
    }

    public DeviceIntegrations getDeviceIntegrations() {
        return deviceIntegrations;
    }

    public void setDeviceIntegrations(DeviceIntegrations deviceIntegrations) {
        this.deviceIntegrations = deviceIntegrations;
    }

    public List<DeviceToken> getDeviceTokenList() {
        return deviceTokenList;
    }

    public void setDeviceTokenList(List<DeviceToken> deviceTokenList) {
        this.deviceTokenList = deviceTokenList;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public Map<String, String> getUnitMap() {
        
        return unitMap;
    }

    public void setUnitMap(Map<String, String> unitMap) {
        
        this.unitMap = unitMap;
    }

    public Date getLastRecommendationInfoDate() {
        return lastRecommendationInfoDate;
    }

    public void setLastRecommendationInfoDate(Date lastRecommendationInfoDate) {
        this.lastRecommendationInfoDate = lastRecommendationInfoDate;
    }

    public boolean isTermsConditions() {
        return termsConditions;
    }

    public void setTermsConditions(boolean termsConditions) {
        this.termsConditions = termsConditions;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHealthMetricPreferences() {
        return healthMetricPreferences;
    }

    public void setHealthMetricPreferences(Map<String, String> healthMetricPreferences) {
        this.healthMetricPreferences = healthMetricPreferences;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPinpointCustomAttributes() {
        return pinpointCustomAttributes;
    }

    public void setPinpointCustomAttributes(Map<String, String> pinpointCustomAttributes) {
        this.pinpointCustomAttributes = pinpointCustomAttributes;
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getDevicePreferences() {
        return devicePreferences;
    }

    public void setDevicePreferences(Map<Integer, String> devicePreferences) {
        this.devicePreferences = devicePreferences;
    }
    public Map<String, RecentHealthMetricData> getRecentHealthMetricValues() {
        if(recentHealthMetricValues==null) {
            recentHealthMetricValues = new HashMap<>();
        }
        return recentHealthMetricValues;
    }

    public void setRecentHealthMetricValues(Map<String, RecentHealthMetricData> recentHealthMetricValues) {
        
        this.recentHealthMetricValues = recentHealthMetricValues;
    }

    public List<String> getNewRecommendations() {
        return newRecommendations;
    }

    public void setNewRecommendations(List<String> newRecommendations) {
        this.newRecommendations = newRecommendations;
    }

    public boolean isOptJuvLabsCustomer() {
        return optJuvLabsCustomer;
    }

    public void setOptJuvLabsCustomer(boolean optJuvLabsCustomer) {
        this.optJuvLabsCustomer = optJuvLabsCustomer;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public Instant getDeletedTimestamp() {
        return deletedTimestamp;
    }

    public void setDeletedTimestamp(Instant deletedTimestamp) {
        this.deletedTimestamp = deletedTimestamp;
    }

    public String getOriginalKiboId() {
        return originalKiboId;
    }

    public void setOriginalKiboId(String originalKiboId) {
        this.originalKiboId = originalKiboId;
    }

    public String getOldestProfileRecommendationInfoId() {
        return oldestProfileRecommendationInfoId;
    }

    public void setOldestProfileRecommendationInfoId(String oldestProfileRecommendationInfoId) {
        this.oldestProfileRecommendationInfoId = oldestProfileRecommendationInfoId;
    }

    public int getDailyActionCountClevertap() {
        return dailyActionCountClevertap;
    }

    public void setDailyActionCountClevertap(int dailyActionCountClevertap) {
        this.dailyActionCountClevertap = dailyActionCountClevertap;
    }

}
```

**ProfileDetails.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Document(collection = "profile_details")
public class ProfileDetails  {

    @Field("profile_id")
    private String profileId;

    @Field("partner_code")
    @JsonProperty("partner_code")
    private String partnerCode;

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getPartnerCode() {
        return partnerCode;
    }

    public void setPartnerCode(String partnerCode) {
        this.partnerCode = partnerCode;
    }


}
```

**ProfileFragmentRepositoryImpl.java**

```
package com.juv.common.secondary.repository.impl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AddFieldsOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOptions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.LimitOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.LookupOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.MatchOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.OutOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.SetOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.SortOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.UnsetOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.juv.common.constants.CommonConstants;
import com.juv.common.secondary.dao.Profile;
import com.juv.common.secondary.dao.ProfileDetails;
import com.juv.common.secondary.repository.ProfileFragmentRepository;
import com.juv.common.secondary.repository.ProfileRepository;
import com.mongodb.internal.operation.InsertOperation;

@Component
public class ProfileFragmentRepositoryImpl implements ProfileFragmentRepository {
    

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveProfileDetails(Profile profile) {
        
        MatchOperation filterOnProfileId = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("profileId").is(profile.getProfileId()));
                
        SetOperation setProfileId = SetOperation.set("profileId").toValue(profile.getProfileId());

        SetOperation setPartnerCode = SetOperation.set("partnerCode").toValue(profile.getPartnerCode());
                
        OutOperation outOperation = new OutOperation("profile_details").uniqueKey("profileId").insertDocuments();
        
        
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(filterOnProfileId,setProfileId,setPartnerCode,outOperation);

        System.out.println("------------------------"+aggregation);
        
        AggregationResults<ProfileDetails> output = secondaryMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Profile.class, ProfileDetails.class);
        System.out.println("------------------------"+output);
    }
    
}
```

$out operator replaces documents instead of inserting new documents.How can i make them insert data instead of replacing them

Comment: Have you checked out [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)?

Comment: @ray yes I tried $merge also it was giving cursor error.can u please help